# Gstreamer videobox alpha border remains black

Tags: video, gstreamer

I've got a problem with that kind of pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
    videomixer name=mix ! autovideosink \
    videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480" ! mix. \
    videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw,width=320,height=240" ! videobox top=-80 left=-80 border-alpha=0 ! mix.
```

The second videotest is well included in the first video, but black borders should be transparent. I tried with gstreamer 0.10 and 1.0 (I prefer to use 1.0) and with several values of alpha. I tried with different video sink to be sure that's not the output that have problems.

I tried to record output in a file too.

I tried other format as I420 for example...

The problem is the same, borders are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an alpha channel to each videosrc. Here is one way to do it.

`gst-launch-1.0 \
    videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
    videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480" ! alpha alpha=1.0 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw,width=320,height=240" ! alpha alpha=1.0 ! videobox top=-80 left=-80 border-alpha=0 ! mix.`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's strange that no documentation (official or not) doesn't give this explanation. All examples doesn't give the "alpha" plugin in the pipeline. A big thanks !